# Why is websocket taking 20-30 seconds to get into the while loop

Tags: python, websocket, discord

I am trying to make it find certain messages as soon as it is sent, but when the message is sent it takes about 20-30 seconds after for the code to finish. Where I have print("entered while loop") it waits right before that.

```
        ws.connect('wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=6&encording=json')
        print("Connected")
        event = recieve_json_response(ws)

        heartbeat_interval = event['d']['heartbeat_interval'] / 1000
        threading._start_new_thread(heartbeat, (heartbeat_interval, ws))
        print("Interval Set")
        token = dtoken
        payload = {
            'op': 2,
            "d": {
                "token": token,
                "properties": {
                    "$os": "windows",
                    "$browser": "chrome",
                    "$device": 'pc'
                }
            }
        }
        send_json_request(ws, payload)
        print("Sent Request")
        while True:
            event = recieve_json_response(ws)
            print("Entered While Loop")
            try:
                print("Entered Try Loop")
                if event['d']["channel_id"] == channelid:
                    if "https" in event['d']['content']:
                        pair = event['d']['content'].rsplit('/', 1)[1]
                        print("U R DUMB")
                        break
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `discord.py`?

Comment: Its a self bot and I dont know how to make it do that.

Comment: You can do that with `discord.py` keep in mind it is against TOS. When running the `Client` use `Client.run("TOKEN", bot=False)`

Comment: How would I ask for it to update nonstop if I use discord.py?

Comment: you would use [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message)

Comment: I tried using on message as you suggested, but it only listens for commands from the token put in it. I am trying to make it scrape from only 1 channel that I specify with channelID and look for a message containing a link somewhere in it and assigning the message to a variable. But I will not be the one who sends the message.

Comment: You can always make an if statement `if message.channel.id == 1234:`

Comment: but right now its only listening to the stuff I type, I have my friend type the same thing in the same channel but it doesnt work.

Comment: Why not just use a bot account? since `on_message` requires `Intents.messages` to be enabled.

Comment: Because I am not scraping from my own server, im doing it from a different server that the bot will not be in.

Comment: try using `bot.get_channel()` and take the history of that channel. That is all I can think of